# Convert imageSource coming from Xam.Plugin.Media 5.0.1 to byte array in Xamarinforms?

Tags: c#, arrays, xamarin.forms, imagesource

```
if (!CrossMedia.Current.IsPickPhotoSupported)
        {
            await Application.Current.MainPage.DisplayAlert("Photos Not Supported", ":( Permission not granted to photos.", "OK");
            return;
        }
        var file = await Plugin.Media.CrossMedia.Current.PickPhotoAsync(new Plugin.Media.Abstractions.PickMediaOptions
        {
            PhotoSize = Plugin.Media.Abstractions.PhotoSize.Medium,
        });


        if (file == null)
            return;

        var tmpSrc = ImageSource.FromStream(() =>
        {
            var stream = file.GetStream();
            file.Dispose();
            return stream;
        });
```

ImageSource toBeConverted = tmpSrc;

- I want the variable **toBeConverted** to be converted into Byte[] so
  that I can send it to my webapi ...

Comment: `File.ReadAllBytes(file.Path);`

Comment: Could it work ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ImageSource` is a way to provide a source image for Xamarin.Forms.Image to show some content. If you're already showing something on the screen your `Image` view was populated with data that came from elsewhere, such as a file or resource or stored in an array in memory... or however else you got that in the first place. Instead of trying to get that data back from `ImageSource` you can keep a reference to it and upload it as needed.

So you could get the byte array from the file after you pick the photo.

```
var file = await Plugin.Media.CrossMedia.Current.PickPhotoAsync(new Plugin.Media.Abstractions.PickMediaOptions
    {
        PhotoSize = Plugin.Media.Abstractions.PhotoSize.Medium,
    });
if (file == null)
return;    
var bytes = File.ReadAllBytes(file.Path); // you could get  the byte[] here from the file path.
```

Answer (score 0):

- This code also worked for me ...

  ```
   private async void Capture()
   {
       if (!CrossMedia.Current.IsCameraAvailable || !CrossMedia.Current.IsTakePhotoSupported)
       {
           await Application.Current.MainPage.DisplayAlert("No Camera", ":( No camera available.", "OK");
           return;
       }

       var file = await CrossMedia.Current.TakePhotoAsync(new Plugin.Media.Abstractions.StoreCameraMediaOptions
       {
           Directory = "Test",
           SaveToAlbum = true,
           CompressionQuality = 75,
           CustomPhotoSize = 50,
           PhotoSize = PhotoSize.Medium,
           DefaultCamera = CameraDevice.Front
       });

       if (file == null)
           return;

       var stream = file.GetStream();
       if (stream != null)
       {
           var StreamByte = ReadAllBytes(stream);
           var NewStream = new MemoryStream(StreamByte);
           // stream = mystream;
           Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() => {
               ImageSource = ImageSource.FromStream(() => NewStream);
           });

           student.ProfilePicture = StreamByte;
       }
   }
   public byte[] ReadAllBytes(Stream instream)
   {
       if (instream is MemoryStream)
           return ((MemoryStream)instream).ToArray();

       using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
       {
           instream.CopyTo(memoryStream);
           return memoryStream.ToArray();
       }
   }
  ```